# How to create a synapse in NEURON?

Tags: python, neuron-simulator

How can I create a synapse in the NEURON simulator using its Python interface? I would like to create 2 Sections and connect them with a synapse, but there aren't any functions for it on the `Section` API or in the [Section docs](https://nrn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/modelspec/programmatic/topology/geometry.html):

```py
from neuron import h

src = h.Section(name="source")
dest = h.Section(name="destination")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NEURON synapses are of the family of [`PointProcess`es](https://nrn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/modelspec/programmatic/mechanisms/mech.html). You can insert a `PointProcess` into a `Section` by accessing it on the `HocInterpreter` and giving it a `Segment` on the `Section`. You then have to create a `NetCon` from a voltage pointer on the presynaptic Section (`src(x)._ref_v`) to the target point process:

```py
from neuron import h

dest = h.Section(name="destination")
synapse = h.ExpSyn(sec(0.5))
src = h.Section(name="source")
connection = h.NetCon(src(0.5)._ref_v, synapse)
```

Make sure to keep references to each piece around or they get garbage collected. Also make sure that you set the proper `connection.weight` (it's an array, so usually `connection.weight[0]`) and that you set the proper attributes on the point process for it to function as well.